# How to compile ng-model using fckeditor in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am going to generate a dynamic html values using ng-model of angularjs. my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/chicks/6pAkL/
        but, fckeditor is replacing our textarea and it is adding its own new textarea. so, I am unable to add ng-model on it.
        fckeditor is on div base its not in iframe.
    **  My html and javascript code is here. **
    =====================================================================
       **FCK Editor Script**
    =======================================================================

```
**TextArea which is gone replaced by FCK editor**
============================================================================
                        <textarea id="content" ng-model="html" cols="30" rows="10" style="background:#f3f3f3">
                      </textarea>
            <input id="cmdShow" type="button" value="Show Content" onclick="ShowContent();"/>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div id="renderHere" compile="html">
               </div>
            <script>
**It is  fetching content from editor**
===============================================================
                CKEDITOR.replace('content');
                    function ShowContent() {
                        var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData();
                        var renderdiv = document.getElementById("renderHere");
                        renderdiv.innerHTML = editor_data;
                }


        **Angular Code**
==============================================================
            angular.module('compile', [], function($compileProvider) {
                $compileProvider.directive('compile', function($compile) {
                    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        scope.$watch(
                            function(scope) {
                                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                            },
                            function(value) {
                                element.html(value);
                                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                            }
                        );
                    };
                })
            });
            function Ctrl($scope) {
                $scope.name = 'chicks';
                $scope.html = 'Hello this is html {{name}}';
            }
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: I do believe it's just "CKEditor" now ;) "FCK" were his initials, but it was too similar to the F word.

Comment: What does CKEditor replace the textarea element with?

Comment: Your fiddle has no content

Comment: @MatthiasDailey: CKEditor creates its own blank textarea